# Rewriting trigonometric expression in terms of $\cot x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Rewrite the following expression in terms of $\cot x$:
>
> $$\frac{1}{1-\cos x}-\frac{\cos x}{1+\cos x}$$

I usually show my work on this site but I'm really lost about this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you get a common denominator?

Comment: @AdamHughes Is it $(1-\cos x)(1+ \cos x)=1-\cos^2 x?$

Comment: That is indeed the denominator, now you should try and combine the fractions into one big one with that denominator. From there you should be able to use $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta =1$ a few times to get your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\require{cancel}\frac{1}{1-\cos x}-\frac{\cos x}{1+\cos x} \\ \frac{1}{1-\cos x}\color{red}{\frac{1+\cos x}{1+\cos x}}-\frac{\cos x}{1+\cos x}\color{red}{\frac{1-\cos x}{1-\cos x}}\\\frac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos^2x}-\frac{\cos x-\cos^2 x}{1-\cos ^2x}\\\frac{1+\cancel{\cos x-\cos x}+\cos^2x}{1-\cos^2x} \\ \frac{1+\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}\\\therefore \csc^2x+\cot^2x$$

If only $\cot^2x$:

$$\frac{1+\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}\\ \frac{\sin^2x+\cos^2x+\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}\\\therefore 1+2\cot^2 x$$

Or you could have just used another identity.

Comment: On the second part, for just $\cot^2 x$, why did you write two $\cos^2 x$ in the numerator? Thanks +1

Comment: @user437158 Because $1=\sin^2x+\cos^2x$. I substituted for $1$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{1}{1-\cos x}-\frac{\cos x}{1+\cos x} = \frac{1+\cos x-\cos x +\cos^2 x}{1-\cos^2 x} = \frac{1+\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x} = \frac{\sin^2 x + 2\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x} =\\ =1 + 2\cot^2 x$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{1-\cos x}-\frac{\cos x}{1+\cos x}=\frac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos^2 x}-\frac{\cos x- \cos^2 x}{1-\cos^2 x}=\frac{1+\cos^2 x}{1-\cos^2 x}=\frac{1+\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x}=\frac{2\cos^2 x+ \sin^2}{\sin^2 x}=2\cot^2 x +1$$

First you get common denominator $1-\cos^2 x=(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)$, in next steps you use $\cos^2 x+ \sin^2 x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

First convert everything to $\csc$s and $\cot$s by dividing numerators and denominators by $1/\sin x$.
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{1}{1-\cos x}-\frac{\cos x}{1+\cos x}&=&\frac{1}{1-\cos x}\cdot\frac{1/\sin x}{1/\sin x}-\frac{\cos x}{1+\cos x}\cdot\frac{1/\sin x}{1/\sin x}\\
&=&\frac{1/\sin x}{1/\sin x-\cos x/\sin x}-\frac{\cos x/\sin x}{1/\sin x+\cos/\sin x}\\
&=&\frac{\csc x}{\csc x-\cot x}-\frac{\cot x}{\csc x+\cot x}\\
&=&\frac{\csc x}{\csc x-\cot x}\cdot\frac{\csc x+\cot x}{\csc x+\cot x}-\frac{\cot x}{\csc x+\cot x}\cdot\frac{\csc x-\cot x}{\csc x-\cot x}\\
&=&\frac{\csc^2 x+\csc x\cot x}{\csc^2 x-\cot^2 x}-\frac{\csc x\cot x-\cot^2 x}{\csc^2 x-\cot^2 x}\\
&=&\frac{\csc^2 x+\cot^2 x}{(\cot^2 x+1)-\cot^2 x}\\
&=&\csc^2 x+\cot^2 x\\
&=&(\cot^2 x+1)+\cot^2 x\\
&=&2\cot^2 x+1
\end{array}$$